# Event Viewer Application Crash - decrypting the error message

Tags: c#, .net, exception, crash, event-viewer

Does anyone know how to decrypt this to find out where in the program the crash is happening from the Event Viewer in Windows?

Faulting module name: clr.dll, version: 4.6.81.0, time stamp: 0x5584e56f
Exception code: 0xc00000fd
Fault offset: 0x004219ca
Faulting process id: 0x141c
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Report Id: 648e6840-f685-11e5-8913-005056ab66a9

Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 0):

This won't tell you where the error is, but a simple Google on 0xc00000fd will tell you it's a stack overflow (so you've reported it to the right place!).  Try catching exceptions in the code, also monitoring memory usage as the program runs, etc.